# Unable to access django projects' named server after deploying on apache virtual host

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, virtualhost

Unable to access django projects' named server after deploying on apache virtual host.

Below is the tag snippet that I have came up with.

```
Listen 8000
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/ecomgroup/ecom/ecomstore-8000"
    ServerName fpshoppingfashionpassion.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    Alias /static /var/www/ecomgroup/ecom/ecomstore/public/static
    <Directory /var/www/ecomgroup/ecom/ecomstore/public/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/ecomgroup/ecom/ecomstore/ecomstore/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess econroot.com python-path=/var/www/ecomgroup:/var/www/ecomgroup/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup econroot.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/ecomgroup/ecom/ecomstore/ecomstore/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

Please let me know if something else goes here.

Comment: what version of apache2 are you running? what dist Linux ?
Show the error. From apache error.log

Comment: @JuanE. I am able to access through ip address from remote system. But not being able to access through named host given. no error is getting logged in `apache2/error.log`

Comment: The host `fpshoppingfashionpassion.com` does not appear to exist.  You can't just make up a hostname and put it in the apache config; the hostname must actually be registered to you, and the address must resolve to a real machine somewhere on the internet.

Comment: `python-path=/var/www/ecomgroup` add the django project dir `python-path=/var/www/ecomgroup/ecom/ecomstore`